# Aligning the elements of <td> tag

Tags: html, css

Please check out this http://jsfiddle.net/karthik64/JHVDn/1/.

Well I believe you got where I am stucked at.See In my Result, I want that `Sean Kingstonnnnnnnnn` to be placed below, if it is unable to fit in the given width but whats happening is `Sean` is printing up and `kingstonnnnnn` in the next line, this should not be happened  I want that to be aligned in a nice manner I dont want them to break up or split. Well I even tried using `text-align:justify` but it did not help me

Please kindly tell me, how do i get over this. I want the table to be used but if there is any other solution, its greatly appreciated it would help in strengthening my Skills.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting **white-space: nowrap;** into the CSS.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID. You should switch to using a class instead, so **id="span_data"** becomes **class="span_data"**.

Comment: Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JHVDn/5/
Note that using **display: inline-block;** won't work in all browsers - I prefer **display: inline-block; float: left;** as pointed out by @Brombomb

Comment: well Just tell me Im very impressed with white_space:nowrap but will it work with all versions of browsers?!

Answer (score 1):

My fork, http://jsfiddle.net/fq347/

- You can't assign multiple elements with the same `id`. Use `class` instead
- Use `display:inline-block` to acheive the wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block` will do it simply, but won't work in older IE browsers.  A simple `float: left` will allow it all to wrap nicely in all browsers (but really defeats the purpose of a span element).